# How to create read-only virtual attributes in Ruby models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, virtual-attribute

I would like to create a virtual attribute that will always be included when you do model_instance.inspect.  I understand that attr_reader will give me the same thing as just defining an instance method, but I would like this attribute to be part of the object's "make up"

How can I accomplish this?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is what is not working in more detail:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_reader :less_secure_asset_url

     def less_secure_asset_url
       self.asset.url
     end
end

>> p = Product.find(:all)[1]
=> #<Product id: 49, asset_file_name: "Etrade_Trade_Conf_Request.docx", asset_content_type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordp...", asset_file_size: 38152, asset_updated_at: "2010-05-04 17:45:46", created_at: "2010-05-04 17:45:46", updated_at: "2010-05-04 17:45:46", owner_id: 345, product_type_id: 1>
```

As you can see, when I use the console it returns no "less_secure_asset_url" attribute

Comment: @bill brasky, nice username :)

Comment: Question is unclear. Is overriding `#inspect` ok? Should `attributes` return that value, etc...
What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: When I get an object - p = Product.find(:all)[0], I want the product to include certain attributes that are not in the database but should be in the object.  Therefore, overriding inspect is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute is in there, even if it doesn't show up. Rails overrides the definition of the `inspect` method of `Object` in `ActiveRecord::Base` to something like:

```
  def inspect
     attributes_as_nice_string = self.class.column_names.collect { |name|
       if has_attribute?(name) || new_record?
         "#{name}: #{attribute_for_inspect(name)}"
       end
     }.compact.join(", ")
     "#<#{self.class} #{attributes_as_nice_string}>"
   end
```

Basically, if it's not a column_name, it's not going to show up. I haven't tried this, but you might be able to call something like `p.as(Object).inspect` to get to the super classes inspect method.  You have to `require 'facets'` to get as. See docs [here](http://facets.rubyforge.org/apidoc/api/core/classes/Kernel.html#M000440).